# How to gather Jacoco coverage information in xml file?

Tags: code-coverage, jacoco, jacoco-maven-plugin, jacoco-plugin

I used following command to gather coverage information in xml file -

```
java -javaagent:/home/user/jacoco-0.8.6/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/home/oracle/jacoco-coverage.xml,append=false,includes=com.myapp.* -jar myapplication.jar
```

This generates `jacoco-coverage.xml` file but it has contents like following everywhere -

```
ÀÀ #
```

and now when I publish it to Sonar it shows code-coverage as **0 %** even though xml file has non-zero size which indicates code was hit.

Looks xml file is not generated correctly. Could you please help to generate correct xml file with coverage information?

Comment: I was looking for something which will directly gather coverage report in `xml` file  instead of `exec`

Comment: There is no other way. `jacocoagent` gathers only into binary `exec`, from which then you can generate `xml` report.

Comment: Thanks @Godin, I went ahead with what you suggested and could achieve what I wanted